# Unable to reference a namespace in another assembly when it partially matches one in the current assembly

Tags: c#, namespaces

I have a project of namespace `SpaceCats.Planet.Types` that has a class called `MajorTomCat.cs`

My test project namespace is `Test.Fiddlesticks`

In my test project, there is a namespace `Test.Fiddlesticks.SpaceCats` which is generated automatically from a WCF service reference

When I do `MajorTomCat cat = new MajorTomCat()`, it says it cannot find `MajorTomCat`.

I try to put it explicitly:

`SpaceCats.Planet.Types.MajorTomCat cat;`

But it still can't find it. Hovering over it, it says

> The type or namespace `Planet` does not exist in the namespace `Test.Fiddlesticks.SpaceCats`.

It appears to be looking in the wrong `SpaceCats` namespace.

I can't figure out how to force it to look in the root.

Any ideas?

Comment: Planet or Planets?

Comment: `using PlanetTypes = SpaceCats.Planet.Types; (...) PlanetTypes.MajorTomCat cat (...)`? Plus, the above comment.

Comment: What happens if you use `global::SpaceCats.Planet.Types.MajorTomCat cat;` or `using global::SpaceCats.Planet.Types;` ? And have you definitely referenced the correct DLL?

Comment: `global::` has fixed it, thanks. I figured there would be some way to force it to look from the root. The Planet/Planets is a typo sorry